# Elementary inequalities exercise - how to 'spot' the right sum of squares?

Tags: inequality, contest-math

I have been working through CJ Bradley's *Introduction to Inequalities* with a high school student and have been at loss to see how one could stumble upon the solution given for Q3 in Exercise 2c.

**Question:**

If $ad-bc=1$ prove that $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+ac+bd \geq \sqrt{3}$.

**Solution:**

Make the inequality homogenous by multiplying both sides by $ad-bc=1$. [*That seems sensible.*] Take everything onto one side so we now want to show
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+ac+bd -\sqrt{3}(ad-bc) \geq 0 \tag{1}.$$
[*That's also a reasonable thing to do. The trouble is coming next...*]

Now play around until you notice the left hand side can be written as
$$\frac{1}{4}(2a+c-\sqrt{3}d)^2 + \frac{1}{4}(2b+d+\sqrt{3}c)^2 \tag{2}.$$
[*What??*]

I played around for a fair while and didn't get to this. I have a suspicion that this question was created by reverse-engineering. What thought processes get you from (1) to (2), without knowing (2) beforehand? How can you get to the solution without pulling a rabbit out of a hat?

Comment: there is a method that applies once your problem is written   as formula (1). An algorithm for repeated "completing the square"   See my http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

Comment: It looks like the first square in formula (2) is chosen to account for all terms involving $a$.  If you subtract this out from (1), you will likely notice that the remaining terms look similar to the first term, but with $a$ and $b$ switched and $\pm c$ and $\pm d$ switched; from there it shouldn't be hard to write that as a square as well.

Comment: Completing the square, with $\,\lambda = \sqrt{3}\,$ in $\,4 \times (1)\,$:

$$
\require{cancel}
4a^2+4a(c-\lambda d)\color{red}{+(c-\lambda d)^2-(c-\lambda d)^2}
 +4b^2+4b(d + \lambda c) \color{red}{+(d+\lambda c)^2-(d+\lambda c)^2}
 +4c^2+4d^2
= (2a + c - \lambda d)^2 + (2b+d+ \lambda c)^2 + (3-\lambda^2)(c^2+d^2)
$$

Comment: I have just posted a natural geometric solution.

Comment: @dxiv Please transform this excellent comment into an answer ! I will immediately upvote it ! Two reasons for that: the clever "completing the square" techniques made easier by initial multiplication by $4$, and moreover, like in the answer by Will Jagy, the fact to "abstract" the particular value $\sqrt{3}$ into a general $\lambda$ helps to understand the specificity of this value.

Comment: Here is a simple solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4033249/42969.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks. In fairness, there was already the suggestion of completing the square in a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4396645/elementary-inequalities-exercise-how-to-spot-the-right-sum-of-squares/4397544#comment9195372_4396645), and the end result in an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4396683/291201). But perhaps it was not all that obvious how to piece it together in an entirely elementary way, so I tidied up my comment and posted an answer along that line.

Comment: @MartinR That's a good find, and I +1'd the dupe vote. Maybe a mod could merge the two questions, since there is not much overlap between the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+ac+bd -\sqrt{3}(ad-bc) \geq 0 \tag{1}$

Completing the squares is made easier by introducing a factor of $\,2\,$, so
let $\,\lambda = \frac{1}{2}\,$ and $\,\mu = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\,$, then the LHS of $(1)$ can be written as:

$$
a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+ 2\lambda(ac+bd) - 2\mu(ad-bc)
$$

$$\begin{align}
= \;\;\;& a^2 + 2a(\lambda c - \mu d) \color{red}{+(\lambda c - \mu d)^2-(\lambda c - \mu d)^2}
\\ + \;&b^2+2b(\mu c + \lambda d) \color{blue}{+(\mu c + \lambda d)^2 -(\mu c + \lambda d)^2}
\\ + \;& c^2 + d^2
\end{align}
$$
$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
= \;\;\;& (a+\lambda c - \mu d)^2 + (b + \mu c + \lambda d)^2
\\ - \;& \color{red}{\lambda^2c^2+ \cancel{2 \mu\lambda cd} - \mu^2 d^2} - \color{blue}{\mu^2 c^2 - \cancel{2 \mu\lambda cd} - \lambda^2d^2} + c^2 + d^2 
\end{align}
$$
$$
= (a+\lambda c - \mu d)^2 + (b + \mu c + \lambda d)^2 + (1 - \lambda^2 - \mu^2)(c^2+d^2)
$$

The expression reduces to the sum of two squares when $\,\lambda^2+\mu^2=1$, as in OP's question.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than  $\sqrt 3 $   here is the matrix algorithm for coefficient $1.$  I will try $\sqrt 3$  in a few minutes

Positivity is shown in matrix $D.$   It is then matrix $Q$   that fills in the linear terms, as in: double your form (coefficient $1$)  is

$$ 2 \left( a + \frac{c}{2} - \frac{d}{2} \right)^2  +  2 \left( b + \frac{c}{2} + \frac{d}{2}  \right)^2  +   \left(c \right)^2  +   \left( d\right)^2  $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Allowing the coefficient $\sqrt 3$  to be replaced by variable $x$ we get

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ x }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ x }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & \frac{3-x^2}{2} & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{3-x^2}{2} \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ x }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ x }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 1 &  - x \\ 
0 & 2 & x & 1 \\ 
1 & x & 2 & 0 \\ 
 - x & 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

with resulting expansion

$$ 2 \left( a + \frac{c}{2} - \frac{dx}{2} \right)^2  +  2 \left( b + \frac{cx}{2} + \frac{d}{2}  \right)^2  + \left( \frac{3-x^2}{2} \right)  \left(c \right)^2  +  \left( \frac{3-x^2}{2} \right) \left( d\right)^2  $$

Once we set $ x = \sqrt 3$  we get
$$ 2 \left( a + \frac{c}{2} - \frac{d\sqrt3}{2} \right)^2  +  2 \left( b + \frac{c\sqrt3}{2} + \frac{d}{2}  \right)^2  $$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Comment: It's worth pointing out that for quadratic inequalities, you can always use matrices (which might not be fair play for a high school student), to figure out what the "complete the square" / "sum of squares" is going to be.

Comment: @CalvinLin yeah... I think, without matrices, I would say  let the first square take care of $a^2, ab, ac, ad$  if possible. Next $b^2, bc, bd.$  And so on, if needed. So, in the case when no diagonal element comes out as zero, just a recipe

Comment: [1] Hi Will ! Your idea of generalizing with an $x$ is excellent: it enlightens the specificity of this special value $x=\sqrt{3}$ (or $x=-\sqrt{3}$) giving a degeneracy (sum of two squares instead of four). Besides, these values are frontier values where the quadratic form changes from positive definite to non definite.

Answer (score 4):

There is a geometric interpretation. Let $v=(a,b),\ w=(c,d)$ denote two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2.$ with lengths  $r$ and $s$ respectively, and the angle $\phi$ between them. Then $$ac+bd=rs\, \cos\phi, \quad ad-bc= rs\, \sin \phi.$$
The left hand of the inequality takes the form \begin{multline*} r^2+s^2 +rs\,\cos\phi \ge 2rs +rs\,\cos\phi \\ =rs(2 +\cos\phi)    \ge rs(2-|\cos\phi|).\end{multline*}
By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we get $$\sqrt{3}|\sin\phi| +|\cos\phi|\le 2.$$
Thus $$rs(2 -|\cos\phi|)\ge \sqrt{3}\,rs\,|\sin\phi|.$$ The last expression is equal to the right hand side of the desired inequality.

Comment: [+1] Very interesting. At the end, I would have done it this way: In the last but one inequality, if you divide by $2$, you get $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin \phi - \frac12 \cos \phi \le 1$, then $\sin(\phi-\frac{\pi}{6}) \leq 1$ which is evidently true, with equality (in particular) for $\phi=\frac{7\pi}{6}$.

Comment: Thanks. Instead I have modified the proof so that $ac+bd$ can be replaced by $-|ac+bd|.$

Answer (score 2):

I agree that it's a bit of a leap, but it's not completely out of the question to arrive at this answer on your own. Here's my thought process on this:

I've got a big quadratic thing and I want to turn it into a sum of squares. The first thing I try is grouping, and the terms $ac$ and $bd$ give me an idea to group like that.

$$ (a^2 + c^2 + ac) + (b^2 + d^2 + bd) - \sqrt{3}ad + \sqrt{3}bc $$

That didn't quite work out because of those last two terms. Since we can't factor these independently, I want to try to find a "link" between them. Basically, if I can put a $c$ in the $ad$ term and a $d$ in the $bc$ term, then it suggests a grouping where $a$ and $b$ are independent but $c$ and $d$ are in both. With that in mind, it's a bit more clear that a $cd$ term would do the trick. Since I can't change anything, I need one positive and one negative, giving me something like

$$ (a^2 + c^2 + ac) + (b^2 + d^2 + bd) - \sqrt{3}(a-c)d + \sqrt{3}(b-d)c $$

That's all the confirmation I need to at least *try* those groups. That means I'm looking for some coefficients that let me factor as

$$ (x_aa+x_cc+ x_dd)^2 + (y_bb+y_dd +y_cc)^2$$

Since $a$ and $b$ are independent, their respective groups are the only way to get [$a^2$ and $ac$] and [$b^2$ and $bd$]. A quick check shows that $x_a = y_b = 1$ and $x_c = y_d = 1/2$. It remains to find values for $x_d$ and $y_c$. I know what their squares should be, so that gives me simple equations

$$ x_d^2 + (1/2)^2 = 1 \\ y_c^2 + (1/2)^2 = 1 $$

which I can solve directly or access the trig center of my brain to realize that $x_d = y_c = \pm\sqrt{3}/2$. This gives me a *proposed* factorization of

$$ \left(a + \frac{1}{2}c \pm \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}d\right)^2 + \left(b + \frac{1}{2}d \pm \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}c\right)^2 $$

and all that's left is to check that it is indeed a factorization (and resolve the signs) by evaluating the $ad$ and $bc$ terms. And, of course, I can factor the $1/2$ out of each square as $1/4$ to get the form that they show.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the identity:

$$(ap+br+cs)^2+(aq+bs-cr)^2$$

$$=(a^2p^2+b^2r^2+c^2s^2+2abpr+2acps+2bcrs)+(a^2q^2+b^2s^2+c^2r^2+2abqs-2acqr-2bcrs)$$

$$=(a^2p^2+b^2r^2+c^2s^2+2abpr+2acps)+(a^2q^2+b^2s^2+c^2r^2+2abqs-2acqr)$$

$$=a^2(p^2+q^2)+(b^2+c^2)(r^2+s^2)+2ab(pr+qs)+2ac(ps-qr)$$

If $a^2=b^2+c^2$, dividing by $a^2$ leaves the four squares intact.

Comment: I don't see the connection with the question...

Comment: @JeanMarie; the question is how the author gets from 1 to 2, which looks like a bit of a leap.